# Угадай число (оценка программы)

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Всем привет.
Продолжаю изучать C#. Написал небольшое консольное приложение: Угадай число.
Оцените пожалуйста. Учел прошлый замечания по названиям переменных, разбивки по методам, комментарий кода. Само приложение работает, вроде ошибок не заметил.
Тыкните носом что не так. Спасибо.

```
class Program
{
    static void Rules()
    {
        //Вывод правил игры
        Console.WriteLine("Правила игры: \nУгадай число, за определенное число попыток. \n\nНастроим условия игры: ");
    }
    static int GenerationRandValue(int interval)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndValue = 1 + rand.Next(interval); //генерируем случайно число и записываем его в переменную
        return rndValue; //возвращаем рандомное значение
    }
    static string Game(int attemp, int rndValue, int interval)
    {
        int numAttemp = 0; //хранение количества попыток
        while (attemp > 0)
        {
            numAttemp++; //счетчик попыток (с какой угадал)
            attemp--; //счетчик попыток (сколько осталось)

            Console.WriteLine("Попытка " + numAttemp + ". Введите число: ");
            int entNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //запись в переменную числа, которое ввел пользователь

            if (entNum == 0 || entNum > interval || entNum < 0)
            {
                return "Будь внимтельнее! От 1 до " + interval + ".";
            }
            if (entNum == rndValue)
            {
                return "Молодец! Ты угадал с " + numAttemp + " попытки.";
            }
        }
        return "Не угадал, это число " + rndValue + ".";
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Угадай число"; //заголовок окна консоли
        Rules(); //вывод правил

        Console.WriteLine("Выберите промежуток чисел от 1 до ");
        int interval = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //запись числа, которое будет промежутком в переменную

        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество попыток: ");
        int attemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //запись числа, которое будет количеством попыток в переменную

        int rndValue = GenerationRandValue(interval); //записываем в переменную rndValue рандомное число, полученное из метода GenerationRandValue
        Console.WriteLine(Game(attemp, rndValue, interval));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Первое что бросилось в глаза - ГПСЧ создается внутри функции которая каждый раз вызывается для получения "случайных" чисел. Это critical bag... Вынести ГПСЧ в переменную класса и создавать один раз.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` - если пользователь введет не целое число, то будет выброшено исключение. Нужно добавить обработку исключений.

Comment: Некоторые ошибки в коде может обнаружить статический анализ. Возможно, вас заинтересует. Откройте свойства проекта, вкладку Code analysis, в комбобоксе выберите Microsoft All Rules. Далее либо отметьте чекбокс Enable Code Analysis on Build - теперь при каждом построении проекта будет выполняться анализ. Либо в основном меню Студии в пункте Analyze жмите Run Code Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основные проблемы у вас по сути две:

1. `Random`. Он у вас не выдаст случайное число при повторном вызове.

   Простой пример:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(GenerationRandValue(5));
   }
   ```

   Результат:

   ```
   2
   2
   2
   ```

   Решение тут банально простое, вынесите `Random rand = new Random();` за пределы метода, не инициализируйте его каждый раз.

   ```
   static Random rand = new Random();
   static int GenerationRandValue(int interval)
   {
       int rndValue = 1 + rand.Next(interval); //генерируем случайно число и записываем его в переменную
       return rndValue; //возвращаем рандомное значение
   }
   ```
2. Вы делаете следующее: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` - вы на 100% уверены, что пользователь введет число? Если нет, делайте проверку.

---

Далее как говорится на вкус и цвет:

1. Я лично просто терпеть не могу всякие `"Hello " + id + "world!"`, это занимает много места, и не всегда читабельно. Воспользуйтесь [интерполяцией строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (С#6++). Тогда строка приобретет более короткий и понятный вид: `$"Hello {id} world!"`.
2. Старайтесь убирать дублирующие строки. Например вы постоянно спрашиваете пользователя число, записываете его и работаете дальше, так почему бы это не вынести в отдельный метод? К примеру мы сделаем метод, который выведет сообщение и начнет спрашивать число, проверяя его на валидность, результат отдаст далее:

   ```
   static int AskUser(string message)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(message);
       while (true)
       {
           if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
               return result;

           Console.WriteLine("Не является числом!");
       }
   }
   ```

   Все, теперь строки:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Выберите промежуток чисел от 1 до ");
   int interval = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   ```

   Мы заменяем всего лишь одной:

   ```
   int interval = AskUser("Выберите промежуток чисел от 1 до ");
   ```